# css in inside jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, position

Hi guys basically what I am wanting to do is find any div with the class of *`video`* and then add a overlayed image to it that will display a play button, then once the play button is there it will do a fancybox popup and play the video

Tasks to do

- play video in fancy box - **Check**
- get image to appear over div : **Check**
- Center image over div: **not check**

The reason is because all the images are going to be different sizes, so i need some jquery that gets the size of the image and then puts it in to the style of the div.

Thanks so much for any help!

```
$('.video').append('<div class="videoOverlay" ></div>');
$(".video").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'padding'   : 0,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'     : this.title,
        'width'     : 640,
        'height'    : 385,
        'href'      : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'      : 'swf',
        'swf'       : {
        'wmode'     : 'transparent',
        'allowfullscreen' : 'true'
        }
    });     

    return false;
});
```

CSS

```
.video
{
    position:relative;
}

.videoOverlay
{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(images/system/play.png);   
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:10; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 40%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO], please take some time to read the [faq]. This isn't really a question, it's more of a request for free help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this css:

```
.videoOverlay
{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(images/system/play.png);   
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:10; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 40%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -75px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
}
```

This way you'll have your play button always centered, as you are absolute positioning it's top left corner in the exact half of the parent, and then adjusting its position by defining negative margins, by subtracting half the width and height of the button, in order to correct it's position.

**Edited after feedback:**

You need to refactor your code a bit. First of all, you are generating this HTML:

```
<a class="video" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?fs=1">
    <span class="video">
        <img id="zoom" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; float: left;" title="Cadastral surveying" src="../images/site/cadastral_map.jpg" alt="Cadastral surveying" longdesc="Survey Solutions - cadastral surveying" width="150" height="120">
        <div class="videoOverlay"></div>
    </span>
    <div class="videoOverlay"></div>
</a>
```

Wich is a bit strange. Try using something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/ZeStnz5c2GI?fs=1">
    <span class="video">
        <img src="../images/site/cadastral_map.jpg"/>
        <div class="videoOverlay"></div>
    </span>
</a>
```

With this CSS:

```
.video {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
}
.videoOverlay {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url(http://surveysolutions.co.nz/images/system/play.png);   
    height:46px;
    width:46px;
    z-index:10; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -23px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -23px;   
}
```

Also remove the `.videoOverlay:hover` styles, as you aren't using them at all.

And it should work. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqypY/) with a working example.

Comment: thanks for that i also need to be able to get the image height as they will always be different sizes

Comment: If I'm understand what you mean, you need to put a play button in front of an image with an unknown width, right? If that's the case, you don't need to know the image's height as you are using % to position the button. The only height you need to know is the button's, and it's always the same. Let me know if i'm getting something wrong. Just to be sure, why are you positioning the background of the play button to 50% 40%?

Comment: http://surveysolutions.co.nz/land-survey if you look on that page i am wanting to put the play in the middle of the picture

Comment: Ok, I see, there are lots of issues in your page xD Anyway, we can solve this problem. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5HNj/), i'll edit the answer with a solution in a moment.

Comment: the problem is that height of the image is different each time the height of the play button is 46px by 46px

Comment: this is the more graceful solution. I tried to solve it through jquery for the challenge but you shouldn't need it (as scumah shows). Even if your image height/width changes you are using % for top and left, and then margins should only adjust to compensate for the size of the play button. The reason it doesn't now is because your code is jacked.

Answer (score 0):

After your feedback I put together this jQuery, which I have no idea if it works or not but should get you started:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("img").each(function(i, pic){ //loop through each img

        var pic_css_width = Math.round((pic.width / 2) - 20); //determine margin-left
        var pic_css_height = Math.round((pic.height / 2) + 35); //determine margin-top
        pic_css_height = 0 - pic_css_height; //margin-top is negative


    //Apply css    
        $(pic).closest('p').find('.videoOverlay').css("margin-left", pic_css_height);
        $(pic).closest('p').find('.videoOverlay').css("margin-top", pic_css_width);
        });


});
```

Comment: the problem is that height of the image is different each time the height of the play button is 46px by 46px